# Using push() in Firebase not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Jumping into firebase. It seems simple but is breaking with the push(). Thanks for any help.

ERROR: Uncaught TypeError: firebase.database(...).push is not a function

```
function submitClick() {

var mainText = document.getElementById("mainText").value;
var mainButton = document.getElementById("mainButton");

// Get a reference to the database service
var database = firebase.database();


// alert(messageText);

firebase.database().push().set(mainText);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for:

```
firebase.database().ref().push().set(mainText)
```

The `push()` method only exists on [`Reference` objects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference), while `firebase.database()` returns a [`Database` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Database).

Comment: Thanks! Reams of docs out there on FB. If there was one spot, where I had an hour to spend, your best link to mainline the concepts?  thanks

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start or (if you learn better by doing) https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/#0

Answer (score 0):

There is a shorter one:

```
firebase.database().ref('/foo/acb').push(dataToSave); // This will push your data in foo.acb.-L6aZ0...
```

or

```
firebase.database().ref().push(dataToSave); // This push in the root of the db
```